# useState array becomes 2 arrays in console.log?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

Im trying to just use a empty array in a react/ts project like this.
`const [companyChatrooms, setCompanyChatrooms]: any = useState([]);`

I then use a useEffect to get it done when rendering component.

````
    async function fetchMyChatRooms() {
    const userCollection = await firestore.collection('user_in_chat')
    const snapshot = await userCollection.where('user_id', '==', myIdNumber).where('chatroom_id', '==', companyChatrooms).get();
    snapshot.forEach(doc => {
    const roomID = doc.data().chatroom_id
    setMyChatrooms([...myChatrooms, roomID])
    });
    }
    fetchMyChatRooms()
    }, [companyChatrooms, myIdNumber])
    console.log(myChatrooms)```

However, my console.log shows 2 arrays with each value instead of 1 array holding both values.

How can i make sure both values are stored in same array?


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0WPD.png  <-- Check how the output looks.
````

Comment: I assume you have an array `snapshot` with more than 1 element and any iteration you are updating the state. This caused multiple re-render

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How would you suggest going about it?

Comment: I move comment in a answer

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have an array `snapshot` with more than 1 element and any iteration you are updating the state. This caused multiple re-render

I suggest you to update state after iterate entire array. Example:

```
const rooms = []
snapshot.forEach(doc => {
    const roomID = doc.data().chatroom_id;
    rooms.push(roomID);
});
setMyChatrooms(rooms)
```

Comment: Good idea! Tried it, for some reason it still displays 2 arrays with 1 value each, and not 1 array with 2 values...

Comment: Can you create a codesanbox example ? It's hard to replicate.

Answer (score 0):

you should set all of them in one time.

```js
   async function fetchMyChatRooms() {
    const userCollection = await firestore.collection('user_in_chat')
    const snapshot = await userCollection.where('user_id', '==', myIdNumber).where('chatroom_id', '==', companyChatrooms).get();
   
// here is the changing
const roomIDs = snapshot.map(doc => doc.data().chatroom_id);
setMyChatrooms(roomIDs )
//
  fetchMyChatRooms()
    }, [companyChatrooms, myIdNumber])
    console.log(myChatrooms)
```

Comment: thanks, however, this doesnt work, as the error occurs: 

Property 'map' does not exist on type 'QuerySnapshot<DocumentData>' firestore